# Operating on SVG files with a large number of elements

Tags: r, xml, svg, inkscape

Assume an `SVG` file that was generated via `R`, represents a graph with about 160000 data points and whose file size is more than 20 MiB. Specifically, let us assume that this SVG file contains 160000 XML circle definitions. For example, see [this graph](https://ufile.io/1hwumlc0). The file is, thus, not atypical for a scientific project.

Assume further that you wish to post-process this file in an SVG editor (e.g., *Inkscape*).

I have found that an SVG file larger than 20MiB is virtually impossible to operate on via a typical SVG editor on a typical user system (x86_64 GNU/Linux, 4 CPUs, 20 GiB RAM), as the file is barely loaded into Inkscape.

Several potential solutions to this problem come to mind, each with a severe drawback:

- Optimize the SVG with tools such as [`svgo`](https://github.com/svg/svgo) beforehand. While the application of `svgo` does decrease the file size by about 20%, it also messes up the graph itself (as is done with the above-linked example file).
- Use a different file format, such as `PDF`. However, editors such as Inkscape typically convert the PDF back into an SVG.
- Save the graph via a different SVG renderer in R. However, both the base command `svg()` as well as the command `svglite()` from the R package with the same name generate graphs of approximately the same size.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to open and manually edit such SVG files with a large number of XML elements?

Comment: Pre-process the output using r so that there are far fewer points.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, your suggestion turned out to be the only viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've certainly managed to find a good stress test for SVG renderers :)

Your SVG contains what appears to be a totally unnecessary clip path that is applied to every data point.

If I surround the points with a group and apply the clip path to the group of points instead, rendering times are significantly reduced.

- Chrome:  255 secs -> 58 secs
- Firefox: 188 secs -> 14 secs

If I remove that clip path completely, I get:

- Chrome:  27 secs
- Firefox: 10 secs.

These changes don't help rendering times in Inkscape unfortunately, but hopefully it helps you somehow.  If you need rendering times faster than that, you likely need to do as Robert says, and reduce the number of data points somehow.

Comment: I tried out a variety of different vector graphic editors. However, the suggestion by RobertLongson in the comments  (i.e., to reduce the total number of points) turned out to be the only viable solution.